# Como exibir a informação no id referenciado?

Tags: javascript, html5

Essa função é a parte final do meu código, ela está funcionando corretamente, portanto não estou conseguindo obter o resultado no local onde desejo, que é na div a qual possui uma tag com um ID. Como faço para que o resultado seja exibido nesse ID?

```
function DisplayInfo()
{
var expdate = new Date();
var visit;
expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime()+(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365));
if(!(visit = GetCookie("visit")))
visit = 0;
visit ++ ;
SetCookie("visit", visit, expdate, "/", null, false);
document.write(visit); 
}
document.getElementById("count").onload=DisplayInfo();
```

HTML onde deve exibir o resultado no local correto:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-4 text-center">
                    <p id="title_cont">Visitante:</p>
                    <p id="count" onload="DisplayInfo()"></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: com `document.write` não vai "escrever" no elemento, use o `getElementById` e então mude o conteudo dele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Olá, boa tarde!***

O comentário que o Ricardo fez está correto, só para elucidar melhor:

***Subistitua***

```
document.write(visit);
```

***Por***

```
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = visit
```

***Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!***